# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object when trying to use list comprehension

Tags: python

I believe this means i cannot use a variable in a loop, but i am kind of stuck on it.

The problem i'm trying to solve is:

> Create an algorithm that finds pairs of primes less than n that satisfy this condition: (p * q) <= n (n is a natural number).

I considered using list comprehension.

My code so far:

```
n = 100

primes = [p for p in range(2, n) if 0 not in [p%d for d in range(2, p)]]

prime_pairs = [((p * q) <= n) for (p, q) in primes]
```

Comment: You were almost there : prime_pairs = [(p , q)  for p in primes for q in primes if p*q <= n]  . Note however that your way to get the list of prime numbers is not efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prime_pairs = [((p * q) <= n) for (p, q) in primes]
```

is the culprit.  primes is a list of integers, so you cannot unpack a single int into a tuple.

As @matina-g has suggested use this instead:

```
prime_pairs = [(p, q) for p in primes for q in primes if p * q <= n]
```

Comment: Thank you, this made my code work perfectly. I am aware that this method is inefficient, however i found the different sieves a little too mediocre, it was more about demonstrating that you can do it with list comprehension . :)